# Grid view with element layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I am developing **android v2.1 API 7** project. I know there is a [good tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) on how to implement **grid view** layout on Android developer website.

What I am confusing is, how can I define a layout which can be used by each cell(element) of the grid layout? Any example on this?

(For example, the tutorial have one image occupy one cell as a element in the **grid view**, what I want is to have a layout for each cell element instead of one single image)

Answer (score 0):

extend adapter and return any view, any layout you want to show, in getView method.